# Is it possible to long press on Apple Maps screen in CarPlay and get directions to that location?

Tags: iphone, maps, car-integration

I'm familiar with long-pressing on Apple Maps on iPhone to drop a pin and then getting directions to that location. Is it possible to long press on Apple Maps screen in CarPlay to a drop a pin?

Comment: Do you use CarPlay and long-pressing doesn't work, or are you wondering whether it would work if you buy one?

Comment: Use CarPlay and it doesn’t work

Comment: CarPlay is a very limited subset of Apple Maps. It doesn't even support multi-touch. I was fairly disappointed by the lack of 'phone-ness' when I first got mine, 5 or 6 years ago. The interface has improved, but it's still very limited. I often just set mine up on the Mac the night before, & send it to the phone. If you do that, make sure you set it to *Go* for a few minutes, then End Route, or it will have forgotten the location by morning.

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 14.4, you're not able to long-press a location on Maps in CarPlay to select a destination.

Apart from selecting a destination on your iPhone prior to using CarPlay, you can only select a destination by choosing a previously entered Destination or by using Search.

I often just tell Siri where I want to go and I'm presented with different options that meet my criteria.